# TMPFS_MAGIC in linux header and error determining the free disk space

Tags: c, linux, disk

I am sorry if I make a "double question" but I don't want separate these two :) By any chance does anyone know what `TMPFS_MAGIC` having the value `0x01021994` is used for? It is defined in `/usr/include/linux/magic.h` and I have found it while running the following code which tries to determine the available space in a linux directory (usually a partition):

```
QString path = "/dev/sde1";
struct stat stst;
struct statfs stfs;

if ( ::stat(path.toLocal8Bit(), &stst) == -1 )
{
    return 0.0;
}

if ( ::statfs(path.toLocal8Bit(), &stfs) == -1 )
{
    return 0.0;
}

return m_diskFree = stfs.f_bavail * ( stst.st_blksize / 1024 );
```

from the gdb command prompt:

```
(gdb) print stfs
$1 = {f_type = 16914836, f_bsize = 4096, f_blocks = 2042909, f_bfree = 2042907, f_bavail = 2042907, f_files = 2042909, f_ffree = 2042267, f_fsid = {__val = {0, 0}}, f_namelen = 255, f_frsize = 4096, f_flags = 4128, f_spare = {0, 
0, 0, 0}}
```

where `f_type = 16914836` is the magic from above. For your information "/dev/sde1" is an external drive, with an NTFS partition on it.

And also the code above does not work correctly for NTFS partitions mounted on linux systems (it works for ext*fs file systems), so I am asking: are you aware of finding correctly the free space for NTFS drives mounted on Linux hosts? The linux command `df` seems to do the job correctly, but I did not manage to find the correct way to do it (yet...).

Thanks, f.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some debugging and sleepless nights, the solution was pretty straightforward. Find the source for df.c and read it. Long live free and open source code.

And the explanation: when you use stat and statfs to find the free space on a hard disk, you do not try to find the free space of the device itself, because that is magic... but, you try to find the free space of the directory where the device is mounted. So, instead of

```
QString path = "/dev/sde1";
```

there should be

```
QString path = "/mnt/DISK";
```

where `"mnt/DISK"` is the directory where the disk `"/dev/sde1"` is mounted. I have used `libext2fs` to find the mount point of the disk, but I am sure there are other better solutions to find it out, such as parsing `/etc/mtab`